# Can I use a registered variable as multiplicand in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, numbers, x86-16, multiplication, emu8086

I want to use a variable as a multiplicand in my program, below is one of the variables, which I'm not sure if it's declared correctly

`chickenPrice db 19`

This is to declare that the price for chicken is $19.
Also, I learned about `AX:DX` that it's 16-bit registers

I want to take the user input as the multiplier, but I'm not sure if `mul ax, chickenPrice` is the correct way to do this.

And I want to know is there a way to show the answer in 3 digits? I have multiple variables for this and the sum might for the multiplication of the variables might require me to display it in 3 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> chickenPrice db 19
> ```

The declaration of *chickenPrice* is fine.

However with the above declaration, using `mul ax, chickenPrice` is wrong for a couple of reasons.

The `mul` instruction only takes 1 operand. This instruction's use of the accumulator `AX` (or `AL`) is implied. We don't need to mention it explicitly.

And we must be aware that the `mul` instruction can operate on 2 different sizes. Either we multiply the byte in `AL` with any byte-sized operand, or we multiply the word in `AX` with any word-sized operand. The choice is yours, but since you defined *chickenPrice* a byte, the byte-sized multiplication will be correct.

```
mov al, ...       <-- Here the number gotten from user input
mul chickenPrice
```

The product of both numbers is now in the `AX` register

[Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos) explains in detail how you can display multi-digit numbers. Look for the code snippet in the *Method 2* paragraph of the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this multiply AL by the memory location where chickenPrice is stored? I thought you would have to do ```mul byte ptr [ds:chickenPrice]```

Comment: @puppydrum64 The OP uses an emulator **emu8086** that follows MASM-style. In MASM, mentioning the name of the variable is tantamount to using the value stored at that address. To obtain the address itself, we would have to write `offset chickenPrice`. Also in MASM, there's no need to mention `byte ptr` since MASM remembers the size the variable was given from the `db` directive. And for MASM the square brackets are more of syntactical sugar than anything else. Plus there's no point including the redundant `ds:` segment overrride prefix. The data segment is already the default for the CPU.

Comment: @SepRoland I've been using UASM and I'll admit I've picked up a few bad habits.